# Highcharts Range Selector does not work with multiple series

Tags: javascript, php, html, charts, highcharts

I have a highchart/highstock where I get my data from a php file. My problem is that If I'm using multiple series the RangeSelector Buttons do not work (In the example the 1h buttno (1 hour) should work. Example: https://jsfiddle.net/mymarcelsql/8xL34qyk/15/

That's my File:

```
<?php
require("php/00connection.php");

$sql =  $conn->query("SELECT read_tickets, write_tickets, epoch_time FROM tickets_available ORDER BY epoch_time;")->fetchAll();

foreach ($sql as $row) {
    $read_tickets[] = $row['read_tickets'];
    $write_tickets[] = $row['write_tickets'];
}
?>

<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {
 
        var categoriesDate = [ <?php foreach ($sql as $row) { ?>
                                '<?php $date = $row['epoch_time'] / 1000; echo (date('Y-m-d H:i', $date)) ?>',
                                <?php } ?>
                            ];

        var seriesReadTickets = [ <?php echo join($read_tickets, ',') ?> ];
        var seriesWriteTickets = [ <?php echo join($write_tickets, ',') ?> ];
 
        var options ={
            chart: {
                renderTo: 'tickets',
                type: 'line',
                zoomType: 'x',
        setSize: 400
            },
            title: {
                text: "Memory"  
            },
            xAxis: {
                categories: categoriesDate,
                title: {
                    text: "Datetime"
                },
                type:'datetime',
                labels: {
            format: '{value:%Y-%m-%d %H:%M}',
                }
            },
            yAxis: {    
                title: {
                    text: 'Available Tickets'
                }
            },
            rangeSelector: {
               enabled: true,
                inputEnabled: false,
                buttonPosition: {
                 align: 'right'
                },
                labelStyle: {
                    display: 'none'
                },

                buttons: [
                    {
                        type: 'hour',
                        count: 1,
                        text: '1h'
                    },
                    {
                        type: 'day',
                        count: 1,
                        text: '1d'
                    },
                    {
                        type: 'month',
                        count: 1,
                        text: '1m'
                    },
            {
                        type: 'month',
                        count: 6,
                        text: '6m'
                    },
                    {    
                        type: 'year',
                        count: 1,
                        text: '1y'
                    },
                    {
                        type: 'all',
                        text: 'All'
                    }

                ]
            },
             tooltip: {
                //crosshairs: true,
                shared: true,
                valueSuffix: '',
                xDateFormat: '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M'
             },
             series: [{         
                 name: 'Read Tickets',
                 data: seriesReadTickets
        }, {
            name: 'Write Tickets',
            data: seriesWriteTickets
        }]
        };
        var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options); 
    });
    
    
</script>
```

But If  I use a single series the buttons are working correctly.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Using `xAxis.categories` automatically sets a type of the axis to `category` and the range selector feature works only with the `datetime` axis type.

You need to convert your data to `[x, y]` format and use the `datetime` axis type.

---

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.line.data

Comment: thanks for your reply. You mean something like that: `$sql =  $conn->query("SELECT read_tickets, write_tickets, epoch_time FROM tickets' ORDER BY epoch_time;")->fetchAll();


foreach ($sql as $row) {
    $read_tickets[] = "[".$row['epoch_time'].",".$row['read_tickets']."]";
    $write_tickets[] = "[".$row['epoch_time'].",".$row['write_tickets']."]";
    $date[] = $row['epoch_time'];
    
} ` And then it should be possible not to use the xAxis categories parameter. Or am I wrong?

Comment: Hi @mymarcelsql, I mean something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/9b2tsxh5/